# Not working CSS selector

Tags: css, list, selector, children

My head is about to explode on this one. Check this fiddle please:

http://jsfiddle.net/337C7/1/

```
section ul li {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

section ul li ul li {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Basically I have unordered list and inside that another one. Im just trying to remove the text-decoration on the children ul. For whatever reason it doesnt want to work.. Am I stupid?

Comment: Pretty weird, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/337C7/17/

Comment: How about wrapping your underline text in `<span />` tags and applying the underline to those?

Comment: Span would be my suggestion also - especially if that second ul is related to the li it's inside.

Comment: How about using a border instead of text-decoration (float and clear also required)?

Comment: @MatthewRapati Yeah thats really weird stuff

Comment: @Jasper Yeah, probably the best way :)

Answer (score 4):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration):

> Text decorations draw across descendant elements. This means that it
>   is not possible to disable on a descendant a text decoration that is
>   specified on one of its ancestors.
>
> For example, in the markup: `<p>This text has <em>some emphasized
>   words</em> in it.</p>` the style rule:`p { text-decoration: underline }`
>   would cause the entire paragraph to be underlined. However, the style
>   rule: `em { text-decoration: none }` would not cause any change; the
>   entire paragraph would still be underlined. (However, the rule `em {
>   text-decoration: overline }` would cause a second decoration to appear
>   on "some emphasized words".)

Comment: 1+ Nice find. I was looking for that.

Comment: +1. I borrowed this sample for my solution - hope you won't mind.

Comment: Using a span inside the li elements would prevent this. Then it would work similar to dropdown menus.

Answer (score 2):

While the browser might render it without an issue, certain browsers will render the text-decoration, and get confused by the containing element (in this case, the `<li>`. This fact is proven by @Matthew Rapati's comment). For example, this is from the MDN article on the issue (borrowed from j08691's answer for completeness):

> Text decorations draw across descendant elements. This means that it
>   is not possible to disable on a descendant a text decoration that is
>   specified on one of its ancestors.
>
> For example, in the markup: `<p>This text has <em>some emphasized
>   words</em> in it.</p>` the style rule: `p { text-decoration: underline }`
>   would cause the entire paragraph to be underlined. However, the style
>   rule: `em { text-decoration: none }` would not cause any change; the
>   entire paragraph would still be underlined. (However, the rule `em {
>   text-decoration: overline }` would cause a second decoration to appear
>   on "some emphasized words".)

You should simply place the child `<ul>` as a sibling, rather than child of the `<li>`, for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla bla </li>
    <ul>
        <li>bla bla bla</li>
        <li>bla bla bla bla </li>
        <li>bla bla bla bla bla</li>
        <li>bla bla bla bla bla bla</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

You should then update your selector as follows:

```
section ul ul li {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

You can see a working [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/337C7/6/)

Comment: But that's invalid HTML?

Comment: I thought the only child of a `<ul>` could be an `<li>`

Comment: Correct. But as we've highlighted already by the comment from MDN, it's the only way to solve your issue.

Comment: Wrong text items. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: So probably the best way would be to add a span right? Since <li>bla bla</li><ul> is not correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

The text-decoration none is working. But the the unclosed li above is affecting the li bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Add a span element around the text inside the first set of li elements. Then change the css so you target the span instead of the li. If you add a class to the li elements, your css will be easier to read.

http://jsfiddle.net/337C7/27/

html:

```
<ul class="first">
                        <li class="first-item"><span>bla</span></li>
                        <li class="first-item"><span>bla bla </span>
                            <ul class="second">
                                <li>bla bla bla</li>
                                <li>bla bla bla bla </li>
                                <li>bla bla bla bla bla</li>
                                <li>bla bla bla bla bla bla</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

css:

```
.first-item > span{text-decoration: underline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/337C7/30/

***HTML:***

```
                  <ul>
                        <li>bla</li>
                        <li>bla bla </li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>bla bla bla</li>
                                <li>bla bla bla bla </li>
                                <li>bla bla bla bla bla</li>
                                <li>bla bla bla bla bla bla</li>
                            </ul>
                      </ul>
```

***CSS***

```
section ul ul li {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: But thats not valid HTML I assume, It might break something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
section ul li /* descendants including direct children */ {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

section>ul>li /* children */ {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

use children selector for the children after you style the descendants. I'm not sure if you wanted the children to be decorated or the descendants of the children so my rules may be reversed. But the children selector goes after the descendants and then should not require an !important rule.

Update per your fiddle

```
col-md-12 col-sm-12 >ul>li /* children */ {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

or

```
section>div>div>div>ul>li /* children */ {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `border` instead of `text-decoration`.  You'll need to `float` and `clear` as `<li>` is block level.  This way you don't have to change any HTML.

```
section ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
} 

section ul ul li {
  border: none; 
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/337C7/33/**